# Python: Some things in package visible, others not

Tags: python, package, visibility

Package structure:

```
World\
    __init__.py
    Chip\
        __init__.py
        grass.py
        snow.py
        water.py
```

(both `__init__.py`s are empty.)
When I do `from world.chip import *` I can use `grass.Grass`, but not `snow.Snow`. Why is this?

```
MUSIC = {
         grass.Grass: "mus_grass",
         snow.Snow: "mus_snow",
         water.Water: "mus_water",
         "default": "mus_grass"
         }
```

`NameError: name 'snow' is not defined`

Comment: Do you have any other imports?

Answer (score 0):

Is not the right way, but you can force the load of your packages:

```
# in your world/chip/__init__.py
from grass import *
from snow import *
from water import *
```

And then, when you import the `Chip` module, you will load all the others packages:

```
# Your structure dirs
$ tree
.
`-- world
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- chip
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- grass.py
        |-- snow.py
        |-- water.py
```

In your `shell`:

```
$ python
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'help']
>>> from world.chip import *
>>> dir()
['Grass', 'Snow', 'Water', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'grass', 'help', 'snow', 'water']
```

Answer (score 0):

if `__init__.py` is empty, there is no reason to expect that `from world.chimp import *` would bring in either to snow or grass modules.

Your post indicates that it brought in the grass module but we can't see everyting on your system.

Is there a `world/__init__.py`  It could have a `from chimp import grass` which would explain the behavior.  You could also have a pyc that is lurking around even though the py files are as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still figuring this out myself, but I believe that you need to explicitly tell the `chip` portion of the package what sub-modules Python should import when using the `*` wildcard.  Inside the `__init__.py` in the `chip` folder, add this:

```
__all__ = ["grass", "snow", "water"]
```

Without this addition, I get a `NameError` on `grass`.  With this change, there is no error.